# oneVsAll in python with fmingc : Iterations: 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, minimization

I am trying to implement in Python one of the assignments of the ML Coursera (recognition of handwritten digits).
Here are the cost, gradient and onevsall functions (includes regularization term):

```
def costfn(theta, *arg):
    X, y, reg_factor = arg
    m, n = X.shape
    cost = (-y * np.log( h(theta,X) ) ) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h(theta,X))
    reg_term = reg_factor/(2 * m) * np.sum( np.square(theta[1:]) )
    J = 1/m * np.sum(cost) + reg_term
    return J

def gradfn(theta, *arg):
    X, y, reg_factor = arg
    m, n = X.shape
    regtheta = np.ones( (X.shape[1], 1) )
    regtheta[0] = 0
    part_one = (np.transpose(X))
    part_two = h(theta, X) - y
    reg_term = (reg_factor)/m * (regtheta * theta.reshape( (n, 1)) )
    grad = 1/m * np.dot(part_one, part_two) + reg_term
    return grad

def one_vs_all(X, y, num_labels, reg_factor):
    m, n = X.shape 
    for k in range(1, num_labels+1):
        initial_theta = np.zeros((n, 1))
        xopt, fopt, iter, funcalls, warnflag = optimize.fmin_cg(costfn, x0=initial_theta, fprime=gradfn, maxiter=None, disp=True, args=(X, (y==k)*1, reg_factor), full_output = True )
        print warnflag
```

For each class (k=1, to 10), I get the following output from `fmingc`:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 0
         Function evaluations: 1
         Gradient evaluations: 1
```

So, there is no iterations done. For some reasons, with the `initial_theta=np.zeros((n, 1))`, the cost function is already J= 0.

Comment: You may be more likely to get an answer to your question if you tagged it with the libraries you're using and/or linked to the assignment that describes what these functions you've written mean. As it stands, I have no idea what you're actually asking here, and no easy way to learn more to put it in to context.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to pass no labels to your function as you do `(y==k)*0`, which is zero vector, always, no matter what is the `k`. This way zero solution is an actual optimum.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = np.arange(10)
>>> y == 1
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> (y == 1)*0
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>>
```

You probably wanted to do

```
>>> (y == 1) * 1
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

or

```
>>> (y == 1).astype('int')
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

### update

The next thing is that you are using python 2, thus you might have some integer division where you would expect float one, thus getting 0 from operations like `1 / m`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2]])
>>> x.shape
(1, 2)
>>> 1 / x.shape[1]
0
```

Thus never do int-based operations, instead use floats (notice dot after "1")

```
>>> 1. / x.shape[1]
0.5
```

Comment: @lejilot: Thanks a lot. I modified that part as you suggested.  The code still output cost=0.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after several hours of frustration, the code is working now:

1) as lejilot pointed out, I needed to use `(y == 1) * 1`
2) make sure that all the matrix vectors have right shape: i.e (#rows,#cols) and not (#rows,). See for example in the hypothesis function h(theta,x).
3) in gradfn(), the shape of the gradient vector matrix grad[] must be changed from (#rows,#cols) to (#rows,), otherwise fmin_cg outputs the Error: `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`. And that's because it tries to do: np.dot(grad[],grad[]) which is not a valid operation for 2 vector matrix.

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/( 1 + np.exp(-z) )

def h(t, x):
    row, col = x.shape     
    hypo = sigmoid(np.dot(x, t))
    new_hypo = hypo.reshape( (row, 1)) # need to reshape (#rows,1)
    return new_hypo

def costfn(theta, X, y, reg_factor):
    # X, y, reg_factor = arg
    m, n = X.shape
    theta_new = theta.reshape( (n, 1) )
    pos = np.log( h(theta_new,X) )
    neg = np.log(1 - h(theta_new,X))
    cost = ( y * pos ) + (1 - y) * neg 
    thetaReg = np.square(theta_new[1:])
    thetaReg_new = thetaReg.reshape( (n-1, 1) )
    reg_term = reg_factor/(2 * m) * np.sum( thetaReg_new )
    cost_term = -1/m * np.sum(cost)
    J = cost_term + reg_term
    return J

def gradfn(theta, X, y, reg_factor):
    m, n = X.shape
    regtheta = np.ones( (X.shape[1], 1) )
    regtheta[0] = 0
    part_one = (np.transpose(X))
    part_two = h(theta, X) - y
    main_term = ( np.dot(part_one, part_two) ) /m
    reg_term = (regtheta * theta.reshape( (n, 1)) ) * (reg_factor)/m
    grad = main_term + reg_term
    grad = grad.flatten()
    return grad

def one_vs_all(X, y, num_labels, reg_factor):
    m, n = X.shape
    initial_theta = np.zeros((n, 1)) #401*1
    all_theta =  np.zeros( ( num_labels, n ) ) #10x401
    for k in range(1, num_labels + 1):
        print k
        xopt, fopt, iter, funcalls, warnflag = optimize.fmin_cg(costfn, x0=initial_theta, fprime=gradfn, maxiter=200, disp=True, args=(X, (y==k)*1, reg_factor), full_output = True )
        all_theta[k-1] = res.xopt
    return all_theta
```

The way matrix operations are done with numpy.array is somehow inconsistent. Not sure if using np.asmatrix() would be better. I'll post the code + demo on Github asap.